# recognito framework's recognition result is not good

Tags: voice-recognition

I'm testing recognito framework for speaker recognition.
I put short(maybe 5~7 sec) wav files.
but return result is always true.

Would recognito need to longer length wav to identification?

Comment: So that means it's always the same key that's returned as best match. Would you mind showing how you create the different keys ?

Comment: I misunderstand about recognized result.
I realize the result that sorting by distance.

Comment: Indeed, I've updated the Javadoc to make it more clear, thx